# Service to put mobile on silent at a particular time

Tags: android

I am working on a Namaz Manager i have save timings of Namaz in database. I want that when Namaz time strat Azaan play and after Azan finished mobile is switched to silent.
I have tried this for one Namaz only but this is not working...

```
public class alarmService extends IntentService
{

public alarmService() {
    super("alarmService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent)
{
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    int i=0;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    while(true)
    {
    try 
    {
        dataBase db=new dataBase(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database=db.getReadableDatabase();
        Calendar calender=Calendar.getInstance();
        int m=calender.get(calender.MONTH)+1;
        int d=calender.get(calender.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String query="SELECT * FROM NAMAZ WHERE DAY="+d+" AND MONTH="+m+" ;";
        String []values=new String[10];
        android.database.Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                values[i]=cursor.getString(1);
                i++;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

                try {
                    java.util.Date date=sdf.parse(cursor.getString(2));
                    values[i]=sdf1.format(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(this,e+"" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                i++;


            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        for(int c=1;c<10;c+=2)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            Date namazTime=sd.parse(values[c]);
            Date currTime=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(currTime.equals(namazTime) && values[c-1].equals("Fajar"))
            {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("Fajr Azan.mp3");
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                wait(3000000);
                AudioManager am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                wait(3000000);
                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

            }

            if(currTime.equals(namazTime))
            {

            }

        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
};
```

Comment: I don't understand these words: **Namaz**, **Azaan** and **Azan**. What language is it?

Comment: These are the word used in Muslim socity Namaz mean Prayer, Azan mean call to prayer........

Comment: OK, thank you. Every day I learn something.

Comment: So, you want that every day, at a specified time (for prayer), a notification sound (call for prayer) plays and the phone is put into quiet mode?

Comment: Well, you need an AlarmManager (that survives reboot, because most people turn their phone off at night) which not only shows an Activity or a Notification but also plays a sound and THEN puts the device in quiet mode. A good starting point is downloadable here: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html, but you still have to find a way to play the sound and to silence the phone

Comment: i already know that i just want to know how to keep service running in background so that it can't be killed by OS even after restart?